# How can I get a first cell address of the page

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the "CELL" formula on excel to get address of the first cell of the page.

for example:
when I input this formula

```
=CELL("address";Page1)
```

it will have output like this

```
A1
```

and when I input this formula

```
=CELL("address";Page2)
```

it will have output like this

```
A21
```

Comment: How are you defining "first cell"? Why have you tagged `vba`? Are you looking for a formula-based solution, or a VBA one?

Comment: the first cell is the cell that located on most top left of the page.

I'm looking for formula-based, but it is okay if it necessary to use a VBA to make/define a new formula

Comment: That is not something the `CELL` function can do. But you or someone could write your own function, a so-called user-defined function (UDF), using VBA. But first. you need to explain what the first cell is: Is it the top-most non-empty cell, the left-most non-empty cell, or the cell at the intersection of the row and the column of the first two respectively i.e. it could be empty? If it is the latter (usually), to clarify, it means that if e.g. `F5` and `B10` are the only occupied cells, the first cell would be `B5`. Please confirm if that is something you're interested in.

Comment: I don't mind if the cell empty or non-empty, i just need get the address of the most top-left cell address of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I've created my own code that solve my question

```
Function FirstPageCell(thepage As String) As String
' Get the first cell of the page

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim iPage As Integer
    Dim iHorPgs As Integer
    Dim iHP As Integer
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    iHorPgs = wks.HPageBreaks.Count + 1



    iPage = thepage
    
    iHP = ((iPage - 1) Mod iHorPgs)

    If iHP = 0 Then
        lRow = 1
    Else
        lRow = wks.HPageBreaks(iHP).Location.Row
    End If

    
    FirstPageCell = ("A" & lRow)
End Function
```

Credit:
https://excel.tips.net/T005823_Jumping_To_a_Specific_Page.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).